# Is there a variant of the STL unordered_map in C++ that allows only earliest placed elements to be added?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I recently discovered a container in C++ named `std::unordered_map`, that will store the key-value pairs for the user. However, what if my program must ignore any hash value that is repetitive in the collection, while still maintaining the key-value pairs property (ideally all the functions too, provided that I have already written a program that prints out all the elements in the `std::unordered_map`) of `std::unordered_map`? Any container that is built-in or any variants of any built-in collections that could satisfy the conditions are appreciated. Postprocessing is also accepted, provided enough efficiency. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for `std::unordered_map::try_emplace`?

Comment: @S.M. I see the post, and I still cannot understand what it means. Can you kindly provide an explanation for the `std::unordered_map::try_emplace()` function?

Comment: Are you saying that you want two keys to compare equal if they have the same hash value? (Note that "same hash value" and "same bucket" have different meanings.) What should happen if you try to access (read) the value for a key where 1) the key was never added to the map, but 2) there is another key in the map with the same hash value? If you want to find the value for the other key, you might have already found the right container (`std::unordered_map`).

Comment: @JaMiT I mean same buckets.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace

Comment: `std::unordered_map` takes a hash function and an equality comparison as template parameters. What you appear to describe is the situation where equality comparison compares two keys equal if and only if they have the same hash. It would be trivial to implement such an equality comparison and set up an `unordered_map` to use it.

Comment: @IanChiang OK, so you want to prevent inserting a new element if it would be in the same bucket as another element. What should happen if a rehash causes two elements that previously had been in different buckets to now be in the same bucket? Should increasing the size of the map potentially cause elements to be deleted? (I'm thinking that [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is somehow relevant here.)